# The sudden change of the gauge in dojox.dgauges. not like in dojox.gauges

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

Is there a possibility that the needle is gradually changing value when is updating like in `dojox.gauges`
You can see in this [example](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.3/dojo-release-1.8.3/dojox/dgauges/tests/test_circular_gauge.html), when you press the button ***set 15***
 the value changed directly to 15.

Is that a possibility to make it gradual passing by intermediate values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you're looking for is `animationDuration`, per the API docs on [dojox/dgauges/CircularRangeIndicator](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/dgauges/CircularRangeIndicator):

> The duration of the value change animation in milliseconds. Default is
>   0. The animation occurs on both user interactions and programmatic value changes. Set this property to 0 to disable animation.

I created a test [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrkeller/BFPuL/)  to demonstrate this:

Markup:

```
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/dgauges/components/default/CircularLinearGauge" data-dojo-id="gauge" value="20" minimum="-50" maximum="50" animationDuration="100" style="width:300px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
```

Code:

```
require(['dojo/parser', 'dojox/dgauges/components/default/CircularLinearGauge', 'dojo/domReady!'], function (parser, CircularLinearGauge) {
    parser.parse();
    console.log('parsed');
    setInterval(function () {
        var newVal = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (100) - 50);
        console.log('setting value to', newVal);
        gauge.set('value', newVal);
    }, 1000);
});
```